Height of a mass swinging on a rope
The adjoint figure shows blocks of masses (assumed identical) rotating in a circle and they are binded by strings. We can see that the angle of inclination is increasing as we are moving to the left. Their radius is changing with $\theta$ as $L\cdot\sin(\theta)$, so as inclination increases the radius is obliged to increase with it.
If we analyse any single block, the weight acts downwards as $mg$ and the centripetal acts in horizontal direction as $m\omega^2L\sin(\theta)$. On breaking them into components we see $L=g/(\omega^2\cos(\theta))$. As inclination increases, cosine decreases and in turn length increases.
Can someone explain to me, why they all end up being in the same line horizontally? I see it is connected with the constant and equal angular momentum, but the rotation also depends on the radial distance from the center?…


Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_pendulum

If I understood correctly, the problem is to find out why, if the masses have the same angular velocity $\omega$, they also must be always at the same height $h$ from the ceiling.
Given a mass attached to a string of length $L$, with an angle $\theta$ from the vertical axis, with angular velocity $\omega$, the forces on the mass are $F=mg$ (along the vertical axis) and $T$ (along the direction of the string). We can also define the radius $R=L\sin\theta$ and the height $h=L\cos\theta$.
Since there is no acceleration along the vertical axis, $T\cos\theta=F=mg$ [eq.1]. We are left with an horizontal centripetal force $T\sin\theta=mR\omega^2$ [eq.2]. From [eq.1] we know that $T=\frac{mg}{\cos\theta}$, and substituting in [eq.2] we find $g\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=R\omega^2$ [eq.3].
Since $\sin\theta=R/L$ and $\cos\theta=h/L$, from [eq.3] we can finally see that $g/h=\omega^2$. Therefore $h=g/\omega^2$. You can see that $h$ does not depend on the length $L$, nor on the angle $\theta$. The height $h$ depends only on the angular velocity $\omega$. Therefore "if you take a picture from the side" the masses are always on the same horizontal line, parallel to the ceiling and at a distance $h$ from it.

As you write, the two components of the tension in the string must obey
$$
\tan\theta =\frac{m\omega^2R}{mg} \tag1
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle with the vertical and $R=L\sin\theta$ is the distance from the axis.  (Note that the mass cancels out; we didn't have to assume all of the masses were equal.)  We can also use $Z=L\cos\theta$ for the vertical position of each mass.  That gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\omega^2R}{g}&=\frac{R}{Z}\tag2\\
Z&=\frac{g}{\omega^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
This relationship tells us that the vertical height doesn't depend on the length of the string, only on the strength of the gravitational field and on the rotational frequency.  All of the vertical positions should be the same.
I think you got thrown because you imagined $L$ as a variable that could change depending on the angle ("As inclination increases, cosine decreases and in turn length increases").
There's an interesting wrinkle which is elided by the problem.  In the limit $\omega\to0$, you know from experience that all of the $R$ vanish and all of the strings just hang vertically — with $Z=L$ now dependent on the length of the string.  Of course if you just set $\omega=0$ then the relationship (2) becomes a useless statement that $0=0$.  I think what happens is that, once $\omega^2<g/L$, the dynamic-equilibrium solution (3) just vanishes.  It would be fun to hang some test masses from a drill bit and see what the transition looks like.
